# What is the best way to implement caching layer on an Oracle DB for reads?

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka

What is the best way to implement caching layer on an Oracle DB for reads? 
So that whenever the db get updated the cache gets too(consistency) and i can query the cache for reads(data),

And is Oracle SCN a good way to determine what changes have been made to the db so that it can be migrated to the cache, and

Apache KAFKA used as the connecting mechanism for data transfer?

Comment: Oracle caches always. That is built into the database. You can also write your own PL/SQL package doing the caching. But your question is a bit vague. It would be much easier if you could tell what you want to actually do. How frequent is your data changed? How big is the DB compared to the RAM available on your server etc.

Comment: look into [ehcache](http://ehcache.org/) maybe

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?